# WARNING: Resulting JSON is truncated as serialization has exceeded the set depth of 100

Tags: json, powershell, azure-powershell

After adding more data to an object in powershell I am having trouble converting the object to JSON again. **I have started with a JSON file containing a list of different azure policies:**

```
[
  {
    "displayName": "API Management service should use a SKU that supports virtual networks",
    "effect": "Audit"
  },
  {
    "displayName": "Configure API Management services to disable public network access",
    "effect": "Disabled"
  },
  {
    "displayName": "API Management services should disable public network access",
    "effect": "AuditIfNotExists"
  }
]
```

These are then used by powershell to gather the JSON data that the policies consist of. These are furthermore turned into Powershell objects so that I can manipulate and change the configuration to what i would like the policy to do. My current problem appears when I try to Convert the Powershell object back to JSON format.
**Current configuration:**

```
$Policies = az policy definition list | ConvertFrom-Json
$BuiltIns = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

# Loop through powershell objects and trim strings before adding them to existing array
Write-Host "Extracting all buit-in policy ids:"
foreach($Policy in $Policies ){
    if($Policy.policyType.ToString() -eq "BuiltIn"){
    $BuiltIns.Add($Policy)
}
}
$BuiltIns = $BuiltIns | Sort-Object -Property metadata.category 
$ChosenPolicies = Get-Content "C:\PATHTOJSONFILE\policyList.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

Write-Host "Duplicating the chosen policies into .json files"
##Looping through all existing built-in policies
foreach($BuiltIn in $BuiltIns){
    ##Testing built-in policies against the chosen policies
    foreach($Policy in $ChosenPolicies){
        if($BuiltIn.displayName -eq $Policy.displayName){
            $Path = "C:\PATHTOCONFIGDIRECTORY\policies-json\" + $Policy.displayName + ".json" 
            ## Turning JSON data from policy into powershell objects
            $CurrentObject = az policy definition show --name $BuiltIn.name | ConvertFrom-Json
            ##Adding metadata that enables custom policies to be viewed in security center
            $CurrentObject.metadata | add-member -Name "ASC" -value ("true") -MemberType NoteProperty
            ##Testing if JSON member "effect" exists
            ##Testing if parameters has member effect
            ##Testing if parameters equals NULL
            if($null -eq $CurrentObject.parameters -or !$CurrentObject.parameters -or $CurrentObject.parameters -eq ""){
                if($null -eq $CurrentObject.parameters ) {
                    $CurrentObject | add-member -Name "parameters" -value ({}) -MemberType NoteProperty -Force
                }
                if(!$CurrentObject.parameters.effect){
                    $memberEffect= [PSCustomObject]@{
                        type = "string"
                    }
                    $memberMetadata= [PSCustomObject]@{
                        description="Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
                        displayName= "Effect"
                    }
                    ##Adding member effect 
                    $CurrentObject.parameters | add-member -Name "effect" -value ($memberEffect) -MemberType NoteProperty
                    $CurrentObject.parameters.effect | add-member -Name "metadata" -value ($memberMetadata) -MemberType NoteProperty 
                    
                } 
                if($CurrentObject.parameters.effect.defaultValue){
                    $CurrentObject.parameters.effect.defaultValue = $Policy.effect
                }
            }
            if($CurrentObject.policyRule.then.effect){
                ##Sets effect to a parameter that later can be specified
                $CurrentObject.policyRule.then.effect = "[parameters('effect')]"    
            } 
            
            ##Removing illegal symbols from filename
            if($CurrentObject.displayName.Contains("[Preview]:")){
                $Policy.displayName = $Policy.displayName.ToString().Replace('[Preview]:', 'Preview')   
                $Path = "C:\PATHTOCONFIGDIRECTORY\policies-json\" + $Policy.displayName + ".json" 
                ##Converting object to JSON and pushing it into its own .JSON file
                $CurrentObject | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File -Path $Path
              } else {         
                  $CurrentObject | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File -LiteralPath $Path
                }
            } 
        }
}
```

**When I run the code I get an error where the script seems like it gets stuck in a deadlock** (not sure if thats correct, it just seems to run forever without making any progress):

```
WARNING: Resulting JSON is truncated as serialization has exceeded the set depth of 100.
```

Is there a way to bypass the limit of the -Depth parameter? Or is there something in my code that makes the ConvertTo-Json branch out forever?

Comment: How does the output file look like? There could be a backreference from a child object to its parent, which causes `ConvertTo-Json` to run "infinitely", only limited by `-depth` argument.

Comment: I think it's this line here - ```$CurrentObject | add-member -Name "parameters" -value ({}) -MemberType NoteProperty -Force``` - you're adding a *scriptblock*, not a *hashtable*, and scriptblocks are deeply structured objects with circular references. Try changing ```({})``` to ```(@{})```

Comment: @zett42 the output file is created but is empty

Comment: @mclayton The scriptblock was indeed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @mclayton I have a follow up question if you don't mind. It seems like this line of code has no effect when run:
```Powershell
$CurrentObject.parameters | add-member -Name "effect" -value ($memberEffect) -MemberType NoteProperty
```
The output file has a parameters block. But it is an empty object block {}